# User model validation fails, how to ensure "old" value is used

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony app which has a User model manipulated via a form to allow the user to change their username.

The model is backed by Doctrine ORM and uses a UniqueEntity validation constraint on the username field so that if they try and change their username to another existing user's username it is rejected.

This part of the logic works fine.

However, I expose the "current user" object to via the application container to use like a global in Twig so I can show the currently logged in user's username in the header of every page.

However, when using the profile form and the user inputs an invalid username, that value remains "set" in the entity object as the page is rendered so that even though the validation rejects successfully and the wrong username is not persisted, the page is rendered with the wrong username.

Is there a simple way to overcome this? The only obvious thing I can think of is to create a second "global" called username which copies the username value on the incoming request before the form is processed and use that in the Twig template instead - but seems a shame to have to hold on to "user" and "username".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should define your user as a global parameter. Instead, the currently connected User is accessible in your Twig template simply using:

```
{{ app.user }}
```

Additionally, whenever you call this `app.user` variable in your Twig, a good practice is to make sure the User is already authenticated, to avoid exceptions. That's why you should use `is_granted`:

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONMOUSLY') %}
    No user, sorry!
{% else %}
    Logged in as {{ app.user.username }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: My bad, I am using {{ app.user }} - in my head I refer to that as "global", though as you rightly point out, it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the user entity before rendering the form.

```
$objectManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$objectManager->refresh($user);
```